# Hanging on the Connect Wall

Tags: knowledge, visual, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

The sixteen paintings below can be grouped into four groups of four, each group being linked by a common theme. The four themes themselves describe a painting, an image of which is the final answer to this fine art Connect Wall. I hope you enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Painting identification

(From left to right.)

First row:

> **[Girl With a Pearl Earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_with_a_Pearl_Earring)**, by Johannes Vermeer.
>  **[Campbell's Soup Cans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell%27s_Soup_Cans)**, by Andy Warhol.
>  **[Little Girl in a Blue Armchair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Girl_in_a_Blue_Armchair)**, by Mary Cassatt.
>  *[Bal du moulin de la Galette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal_du_moulin_de_la_Galette)*, by Renoir.

Second row:

> **"[We Can Do It!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Can_Do_It!)"**, by J. Howard Miller.
>  **[Luncheon of the Boating Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luncheon_of_the_Boating_Party)**, by Renoir.
>  **[Girl in a Chemise](https://www.pablopicasso.org/girl-in-a-chemise.jsp)**, by Pablo Picasso.
>  **[Water Lilies](http://Water%20Lilies)**, by Monet.

Third row:

> **[The First Outing/At The Theatre](https://www.wikiart.org/en/pierre-auguste-renoir/the-first-outing-1876#:%7E:text=Home%2F%20Artists%20%2F%20Impressionism%20..,Auguste%20Renoir%2F%20The%20First%20Outing)**, by Renoir.
>  **[A Water Mill](https://www.john-constable.org/A-Water-Mill.html)**, by John Constable.
>  **[Le Chahut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chahut)**, by Georges Seurat.
>  **"[Ete Cannes Hiver](https://www.art.com/products/p10287236-sa-i805968/peri-ete-cannes-hiver.htm)"**, by Peri.

Fourth row:

> **[Monhegan Island](https://www.georgewesleybellows.org/Monhegan-Island.html)**, by George Wesley Bellows.
>  **Portrait of girl (unfinished)**, by Frida Kahlo.
>  **By the fountain**, by Bryan Larsen.
>  **[The Umbrellas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Umbrellas_(Renoir))**, by Renoir.

### The groups

First group:

> **Renoir paintings.**
>
>  Bal du moulin de la Galette, The Umbrellas, The First Outing/At the Theatre, and Luncheon of the Boating Party.

Second group:

> **Paintings of girls.**
>
>  Girl With a Pearl Earring, Little Girl in a Blue Armchair, Girl in a Chemise, and Portrait of girl.

Third group:

> **Paintings of water.**
>
>  Monhegan Island, Water Lilies, By the Fountain, and A Water Mill.

Fourth group:

> **Has "can" in it.**
>
>  We Can Do It, Campbell's Soup Cans, Ete Cannes Hiver, and Le Chahut (can-can dancers).

### The final painting

> [image]
>  **"A Girl With A Watering Can", by Renoir.**

Comment: Perfectly done! Not the hardest puzzle, but I love the painting that is the final answer.

Comment: @JeremyDover Me too! Very clever and fun puzzle. I had a great time with this one.